# humanmade / S3-Uploads not uploading media on S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

humanmade / S3-Uploads not uploading media on S3 bucket. Media directly uploading in wp-content folder.

I tried to check connection with WP-CLI.

It's connected successfully.

I'm also able to list the media files from bucket to terminal.

I don't understand, why media still uploading in wp-content even if plugin is activated and all required information added in wp-config file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.